# Will not viewModelScope.launch block main UI?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The Code A use the coroutine of `viewModelScope.launch{ ... }`, I think it will not block main UI, right?

**Added Content:**

To Tenfour04: Thanks!

I display the function `soundDb()`, the `soundDb()` is a suspend function, but maybe it need run long time! By your opinion, will the App maybe cause "Application Not Responding" error?

**Code A**

```
class HandleMeter: ViewModel() {
    var myInfo = mutableStateOf("Hello")
    var a = 1

    fun calCurrentAsyn() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            var b = 0.0
            for (i in 1..5) {
                b = b + soundDb()
                delay(100)
            }
            b = b / 5.0
            myInfo.value = b.toString() + " OK Asyn  " + a++.toString()
        }
    }

}

suspend fun soundDb(): Double {
    var k=0.0
    for (i in 1..500000000){
        k=k+i
    }
    return k
}
```

**Added content second:**

To Tenfour04: Thank you very much !

Which one is better between Code B and Code C, or are they the same?

**Code B**

```
class HandleMeter: ViewModel() {
    var myInfo = mutableStateOf("Hello")
    var a = 1

    fun calCurrentAsyn() {
        viewModelScope.launch (Dispatchers.Default){
            var b = 0.0
            for (i in 1..5) {
                b = b + soundDb()
                delay(100)
            }
            b = b / 5.0
            myInfo.value = b.toString() + " OK Asyn  " + a++.toString()
        }
    }

}

suspend fun soundDb(): Double {
    var k=0.0
    for (i in 1..500000000){
        k=k+i
    }
    return k
}
```

**Code C**

```
class HandleMeter: ViewModel() {
    var myInfo = mutableStateOf("Hello")
    var a = 1

    fun calCurrentAsyn() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            var b = 0.0
            for (i in 1..5) {
                b = b + soundDb()
                delay(100)
            }
            b = b / 5.0
            myInfo.value = b.toString() + " OK Asyn  " + a++.toString()
        }
    }

}

suspend fun soundDb(): Double = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    var k=0.0
    for (i in 1..500000000){
        k=k+i
    }
    return@withContext k  //I fixed it
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A coroutine launched from `viewModelScope` runs on the Main dispatcher by default. It will not block the Main thread as long as you don't call any blocking functions in it. If you need to call a blocking function, you can wrap it in `withContext` and specify a Dispatcher other than `Dispatchers.Main`.

The only suspicious thing I see in your code is `soundDb()`. If that is a blocking function, then this coroutine *will* block the main thread.

A function can be in one of three categories.

- Regular non-blocking
- Regular blocking
- Suspending (non-blocking)

It's possible to create a blocking suspending function, but by convention this is forbidden because it's confusing and defeats the purpose of having a suspend function. The compiler will warn you if it's able to detect a blocking function call in a suspend function. Not all blocking functions can be detected by the compiler.

**Edit**

Incrementing something 500 million times isn't going to take enough time to cause an ANR error, but maybe it could cause a noticeable stutter in the UI. When you do something like a long-running calculation, it can be considered blocking, and so this would be an invalid suspend function. You can fix it by wrapping the blocking work in `withContext` so it uses a Dispatcher that can handle blocking work. Now the suspend function is non-blocking (which by convention should always be how you compose suspend functions) so it is safe to call from any coroutine, regardless of what dispatcher that coroutine is currently using.

```
suspend fun soundDb(): Double = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    var k=0.0
    for (i in 1..500000000){
        k=k+i
    }
    k
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: I updated my answer to follow up with your edit.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content  second  in the question?

Comment: And more, should the `return k`  be   `return@withContext k` in your code of your edit content? right?

Comment: Yes, I missed removing the return keyword. You can use `return@withContext k` or just put `k` by itself since the last expression of a lambda is implicitly a return value. Code B doesn’t make sense. The function is marked `suspend` but doesn’t call any suspend functions so it doesn’t actually suspend. And since it’s blocking (does a long computation in this case) it breaks the convention that a suspend function must never block.